# Creating a host application

Tags: ssh

How can I create an application that can transfer binary executables from one computer to another? That is, from one IP address to another, in Linux.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many existing file transfer methods? Also how is your question related to SSH?

Comment: @David Foerster i need to create an application, which when triggered or opened, sends a set of executables into another computer automatically. (Without giving commands for each executables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create such an application. It already exists on your system!

To copy any file to another system, simply run the following:

```
scp /path/to/file/locally user@remotehost:/path/you/want/the/file/remote
```

You may still need to SSH into your remote host and change permissions, but `scp` will take care of the copying itself. See `man scp` for more details.

Alternatively, you can use `rsync`, which offers a few benefits, but it requires that `rsync` be set up on the server you're copying to. See `man rsync` for more detail.